# What do I need to create web based GIS application to show GTFS data

Tags: web-mapping, web-service, web

I need to create several GIS based application and embed them on a web page for professional development. I need a cost effective solution and don't have big budget. Any help in right direction and to get started is appreciated (case study etc.).

Comment: Use Google Map API with Directions/Transit http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ca/2012/06/public-transit-routing-and-layer-now.html and https://developers.google.com/transit/google-transit

Answer (score 2):

An answer a bit generic without more details.

An [introduction to GTFS](http://openplans.org/2012/08/the-openplans-guide-to-gtfs-data/) to read

You also need to import GTFS in database

- [GTFS DB](http://code.google.com/p/gtfsdb/)
- [gtfs SQL importer](http://cbick.github.io/gtfs_SQL_importer/)

For viewing, really depend but if no routing needed, just use you db to make SQL join from tables and export features to geojson (e.g [PostGIS](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/267-Creating-GeoJSON-Feature-Collections-with-JSON-and-PostGIS-functions.html)) if you need vector.

Consume this GeoJson with [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) or [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org/)

If you need raster, use [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/) or [Mapserver](http://mapserver.org) to generate images from GTFS using WMS standard and consume it also from Leaflet or OpenLayers